# Title Remove from the page

Tags: javascript, title

I want delete the title from this website (need to remove "| Wix.com"), this text will be automatically added when I click on different pages.

Please suggest me any idea to get this done.
Its a free site. I hope there must be a way to remove it.

Link : http://www.scs-qa.com/panamera-old

Comment: It's probably against the ToS to do this, so no. Purchase their premium package...

Comment: Can't be done through CSS, JavaScript has to be used. Set the `document.title` property. If you *really* need to "lock" the title, without knowing the cause of the title changer, use `setInterval` to periodically set `document.title = 'yourtitle here';`

Comment: Try something like `document.title = 'Panamera Trading'`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.title = "The new title goes here.";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Against ToS. need to upgrade with Premium Package.